# Flex - Printing Graphics

Tags: apache-flex, printing

Is it possible to print in an image, high resolution png/jpg file, within `Flex` with a print quality greater than 72DPI?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear you can, this is taken straight from the Adobe Flex help

> Note: A point is a print unit of
>   measurement that is 1/72 of an inch.
>   Flex automatically maps 72 pixels to
>   one inch (72 points) of printed
>   output, based on the printer settings.